# Find all numbers after a character, separated by commas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a DataFrame that I'd like to extract numbers from. The rows all follow the same format:

```
18             cc9   =1 then do i=10;hcc(i)=0;end;
19    cc15  =1 then do i=16,17,18,19;hcc(i)=0;end;
```

and I would like to extract all of the numbers after the `i=` that are separated by commas. They can be anywhere from 1-3 digits and there is always at least one number.

I know I can grab the first number with `(?<=i=)([0-9]*)` but I'm not sure how to grab all of them. The desired output would be:

```
18 [10]
19 [16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your regex to match any other number that might appear:

```
(?<=i=)([\d]{1,3}(,\s?[\d]{1,3})*)
```

Working example:
https://regex101.com/r/vYt9Ey/1

Note that I have changed to force the digits to be between 1 and 3 digits, also added the possibility of a space after the coma.